# An exercise from Shapiro's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction, abelian-groups

Ex. 8 of the first chapter. The statement is as follows.

This exercise is higly recommended if you want or need to practice induction proofs. We define $a^2$ as $a*a$, $a^3$ as $a*a*a$, and for $n $ a positive integer $a^n=a*a*a*...*a$ ($n$ copies of a).

a) If $(G,*)$ is an abelian group, then show that $(a*b)^n=a^n*b^n$ for all positive integers $n$.

[This I proved it easily with mathematical induction using the commutativity and associativity properties of an abelian group.]

b) If n is positive integer show $(a^n)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^n $.

Here I am puzzled how to proceed. I did not have any success with induction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$(a^{n})^{-1} *a^{n}=e(identity)$

$(a^{-1})^{n}*a^{n}=(a^{-1}*a^{-1}*...*a^{-1})*(a*a*...*a)=e(identity) $ using associativity.

So

$(a^{n})^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{n}$ by uniqueness of inverse.

Comment: Thanks. I am puzzled because this exercise appears before the uniqueness of inverse property. Otherwise I have thought myself about a similar proof. Also the author has not defined yet that $(a^n)^{-1} $ denotes the inverse of a^n $ in a group (G,*).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).